# What to return for a non-void function when exception occurs, without using exception? C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement binary search tree. I have both private and public get() methods. For the private get() I return the Node object, or an exception if that Node cannot be found. For public get() I return the value of the Node object, which is std::string or catch that exception. Users only call public get() and I am trying to avoid letting users use exception. That's the reason why I catch the exception in public get() instead of rethrowing it to users. My question is that, how to terminate the function when public get() catches the exception, since my return type is std::string. I tried to return -1 or std::terminate() but they didn't work. Is there any way to handle this or I have to rethrow the exception or change my return type? Thank you. Here are my codes.

```
// public
std::string BST::get(int key) {
  Node *node;
  try {
    node = get(key, my_root);
  } 
  catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
    std::cout << oor.what() << std::endl;
    // How to let the function terminate here?
  }    
  return node->value;
}

//private
Node* BST::get(int key, Node* root) {
  if (root == NULL) {
      throw std::out_of_range("Cannot find.");
  }
  if (key < root->key) {
      return get_node(key, root->left);
  } else if (key > root->key) {
      return get_node(key, root->right);
  } else {
      return root;
  }
}
```

Comment: You get to decide how to represent "the item does not exist". You could use an empty string, for example.

Comment: Alternatively, one way of representing a nullable object is to use a pointer, though you have to be more mindful of memory management if you go that route.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to "leave" a function before reaching the end of that function.  Is that correct?

Comment: I've recently seen a proposal of returning a `std::exception` (not throwing it), or some other exception class. Or perhaps an `boost::optional<std::exception>`. However, if you go this route, you may want to pass your "true return" by reference to your function.

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes, and the function has a non-void return type (like std::string). Also avoid to use exception. Thank you!

Comment: Just expose the exception.  Your current idea has none of the advantages of avoiding exceptions (because they are still used initernally) and all of the disadvantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reserve one possible return value to indicate an error.

For example, a returned `std::string` may contain an empty string (`""`) - assuming there is no way an empty string can be returned if no error occurs.

If returning a pointer, returning `NULL` is pretty common to indicate an error.

If returning an `int`, pick some value that indicates an error (common choices are zero if only non-zero results are expected, the maximum value of an int).

Answer (score 4):

Consider returning a pair with a boolean and a string.

```
std::pair<bool, std::string> BST::get(int key) {
    Node *node;
    try {
        node = get(key, my_root);
    } 
    catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
        std::cout << oor.what() << std::endl;
        // How to let the function terminate here?
        return std::make_pair(false, "");
    }    
    return std::make_pair(true, node->value);
}
```

The problem with using a magic value to indicate the value is missing is there's always a chance that value will actually be used.

Comment: Interesting. I never think of returning a pair. What does that boolean do? Like, if the user detects that bool is "false", then it choose not to print anything. If the bool is "true", then it prints the string?

Comment: The boolean indicates whether the key was found. Yes, your example of printing is one possible thing the caller could do.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, it will be an API agreement to return a specific value. Usually it will be something like a blank string, but if a blank string is a valid return it could be some other value that wouldn't come up otherwise.

```
std::string BST::get(int key) {
    Node *node;
    try {
        node = get(key, my_root);
    } 
    catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
        return std::string("0xDEADBEEF");
    }    
    return node->value;
}
```

Otherwise, you could go with a C style return, where you return an integer specifying whether it worked or not and take another parameter to fill in with the ouput if it's found. (Not very C++ like, I know, but it works!)

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that, how to terminate the function when public get() catches the exception

A `return` statement is valid anywhere in your function.

It signifies that control should return to the function that called it.

```
std::string BST::get(int key) {
  Node *node;
  try {
    node = get(key, my_root);
  } 

  catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
    std::cout << oor.what() << std::endl;
    return std::string(); // I choose the empty string to mean "key not found"
  } 
  return node->value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best self-commenting solutions to your problem are:

1. Return a dedicated class templated on your expected return type that can alternatively hold relevant error information. Consequently, the class would be named e.g. `template<class T> class Expected { /* ... /* }`. To dig deeper into this option, check Alexandresu's talk: [Systematic Error Handling in C++](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C). You can also find a suggestion for incorporating this into boost: [Boost.Expected
   Google summer of code proposal](http://hyc.io/boost/boost-expected-proposal.pdf). Or into the std: [A proposal to add a utility class to represent expected monad](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4015.pdf).
   Since all these are mere proposals and since I have found such error handling to be very project-specific, you would of course need to roll out your own class along the line of the references.

   2. Use `boost::optional<std::string>`. The de-facto standard answer to your question. It has no room for putting error information in the unexpected case, but that appears irrelevant for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic approaches to this:

1. You reserve a special value to signal the error condition.
2. You use a side channel to communicate the error condition. Here is the complete list of possible side channels that come to my mind:

   1. You return a pointer to your string. This allows you to return a `nullptr` in case of an error (the pointer value is the side channel).
   2. You return an object that contains both the intended return value and a possible error condition.
   3. You use one reference/pointer argument to serve as the side channel. For instance, you could declare your public getter as:

      ```
      std::string get(int key, int* error = nullptr);
      ```

      If the `error` argument is not null, you simply set `*error` to signal whether an error occured. You also return an empty string in the case of an error (independent of whether `error` is null).

Each of these has some advantages, and some disadvantages. Here are some of the more important ones:

- Special values constrain the possible uses. Unless you know precisely what your users require (unlikely), using the empty string will disallow some uses of your class. Some users *will* need to store empty strings.
- Returning an `std::pair<>` or similar makes usage clumsy. The returned object needs to be introspected explicitly using a new variable.
- Likewise, the error argument approach requires the variable for the error argument to be declared before the function is called. However, it also allows the user to pass a `nullptr` if they are content with the value that you return on error. I. e. users who need the empty string as a value will use the error argument, users who don't need to distinguish between an empty string and an unset value don't need to do anything special.